# Invalid argument : You must feed a value for placeholder tensor with dtype float and shape [64,1]

Tags: tensorflow

I got unexpected error when running below code :

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  print('Initialized')
  mean_loss = 0
  for step in xrange(num_steps) :
    print ("Train data ",len(train_data))
    batch_inputs, batch_labels = generate_batches(train_dataset, batch_size=64, unrollings=5) 
    feed_dict = dict()
    for i in range(unrollings):
       batch_labels[i] = np.reshape(batch_labels[i], (batch_size, 1))
       batch_inputs[i] = np.array(batch_inputs[i]).astype('int32')
       batch_labels[i] = batch_labels[i].astype('float32')
       print (train_inputs[i], train_labels[i])
       feed_dict = {train_inputs[i] : batch_inputs[i],  train_labels[i] : batch_labels[i]}
       _, l, predictions, lr = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction, learning_rate], feed_dict=feed_dict)
       mean_loss += l
```

Here is the generating batches, lstm cell and calculating loss code :

```
def generate_batches(raw_data, batch_size, unrollings):
 global data_index
 data_len = len(raw_data)
 num_batches = data_len // batch_size
 inputs = []
 labels = []
 label = np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, 1), dtype=np.float)
 print (num_batches, data_len, batch_size)
 for j in xrange(unrollings) : 
    inputs.append([])
    labels.append([])
    for i in xrange(batch_size) :   
        inputs[j].append(raw_data[i + data_index])
        label[i, 0] = raw_data[i + data_index + 1]
    data_index = (data_index + 1) % len(raw_data)
    print (len(inputs), len(inputs[0]), len(labels), label.shape)
    labels[j].append(label.tolist())
 return inputs, labels        
embedding_size = 128
num_nodes = 32
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default(): 

  # Parameters:
  # Input,Forget,Candidate,Output gate: input, previous output, and bias.
  ifcox = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([embedding_size, num_nodes*4], -0.1, 0.1))
  ifcom = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_nodes, num_nodes*4], -0.1, 0.1))
  ifcob = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, num_nodes*4]))

  # Variables saving state across unrollings.
  saved_output = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, num_nodes]), trainable=False)
  saved_state = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batch_size, num_nodes]), trainable=False)
  # Classifier weights and biases.
  w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_nodes, 1], -0.1, 0.1))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

  # Definition of the cell computation.
  def lstm_cell(i, o, state):
    embeddings = tf.Variable(
        tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
    embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, i) 
    i = tf.to_float(embed)
    print (i.get_shape())
    combined = tf.matmul(i, ifcox) + tf.matmul(o, ifcom) + ifcob
    input_gate = tf.sigmoid(combined[:, 0:num_nodes])
    forget_gate = tf.sigmoid(combined[:, num_nodes:2*num_nodes])
    update = tf.sigmoid(combined[:, 2*num_nodes:3*num_nodes])
    state = forget_gate * state + input_gate * tf.tanh(update)
    output_gate = tf.sigmoid(combined[:, 3*num_nodes:4*num_nodes])
    return output_gate * tf.tanh(state), state 

  train_data = list()
  train_label = list()
  for _ in range(unrollings) :
    train_data.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size], dtype=tf.int32))
    train_label.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float32))
  train_inputs = train_data[:unrollings]
  train_labels = train_label[:unrollings]
  print (train_inputs, train_labels)
  outputs = list()
  output = saved_output
  state = saved_state

  for i in train_inputs :
    output, state = lstm_cell(i, output, state)
    outputs.append(output)

  # State saving across unrollings.
  with tf.control_dependencies([saved_output.assign(output),saved_state.assign(state)]):
    # Classifier.
    logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(tf.concat(0, outputs), w, b)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.to_float(tf.concat(0, train_labels))))

  # Optimizer.
  global_step = tf.Variable(0)
  learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(10.0, global_step, 5000, 0.1, staircase=True)
  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
  gradients, v = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
  gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.25)
  optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, v), global_step=global_step
```

The error :

```
    tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:940] Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_3' with dtype float and shape [64,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder_3 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[64,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb_rnn.py", line 232, in <module>
    _, l, predictions, lr = session.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction, learning_rate], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 710, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 908, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 958, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 978, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_3' with dtype float and shape [64,1]
     [[Node: Placeholder_3 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[64,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'Placeholder_3', defined at:
  File "ptb_rnn.py", line 163, in <module>
    train_label.append(tf.placeholder(shape=[batch_size, 1], dtype=tf.float32))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1212, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1530, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 703, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2317, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

It looks like I am not feeding using feed_dict the value to the tensor train_labels[i] with size (64, 1). But when I print using batch_labels[i].shape I get size (64,1) and dtype of both is float32.
The train_input has size (64,) and batch_inputs also has size (64, ) and both of same dtype.
So, where is the `error` in my code?

P.S. I think the error is in line where I am reshaping batch_labels `batch_labels[i] = np.reshape(batch_labels[i], (batch_size, 1))`. Is that the dimension or rank gets changed ? That could be one reason that train_labels[i] does not accept the size of batch_labels as (64, 1) as its dimension and rank may not be the same.As 3-d batch_labels[i] gets converted to 2-d (batch_size, 1) so does the rank increase? Below is generating batch output of 1 unrolling : `([9976, 9980, 9981, 9982, 9983, 9984, 9986, 9987, 9988, 9989, 9991, 9992, 9993, 9994, 9995, 9996, 9997, 9998, 9999, 2, 9256, 1, 3, 72, 393, 33, 2133, 0, 146, 19, 6, 9207, 276, 407, 3, 2, 23, 1, 13, 141, 4, 1, 5465, 0, 3081, 1596, 96, 2, 7682, 1, 3, 72, 393, 8, 337, 141, 4, 2477, 657, 2170, 955, 24, 521, 6], [[[9980.0], [9981.0], [9982.0], [9983.0], [9984.0], [9986.0], [9987.0], [9988.0], [9989.0], [9991.0], [9992.0], [9993.0], [9994.0], [9995.0], [9996.0], [9997.0], [9998.0], [9999.0], [2.0], [9256.0], [1.0], [3.0], [72.0], [393.0], [33.0], [2133.0], [0.0], [146.0], [19.0], [6.0], [9207.0], [276.0], [407.0], [3.0], [2.0], [23.0], [1.0], [13.0], [141.0], [4.0], [1.0], [5465.0], [0.0], [3081.0], [1596.0], [96.0], [2.0], [7682.0], [1.0], [3.0], [72.0], [393.0], [8.0], [337.0], [141.0], [4.0], [2477.0], [657.0], [2170.0], [955.0], [24.0], [521.0], [6.0], [9207.0]]])`

Comment: Can you try with a more recent version of the code and report the backtrace?

Comment: More recent version of the code??

Comment: You are getting this error because the placeholder was not resolved. Make sure the `feed_dict` is constructed properly.

Comment: train_inputs is of dtype int32 and size (batch_size,) so is batch_inputs. Same is the case of train_labels which is of dtype float32 and size (batch_size, 1) so is the size of batch_labels. All are unrollings times i.e. 5 times so feeding the network one batch after another unrolling times. So, "constructed properly" means ?

Comment: The third or fourth placeholder did not resolve, for some reason it's not there in the feed_dict.